# Print comma instead of period in node near coord

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I need to print the Y-values for each point with a comma for decimal seperator. See my MWE. The data is provided as a .csv within my folder.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    %strict,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    exponent-product=\cdot,
    detect-all
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{
    X   Y
    0   0.03
    63  0.04
    118 0.09
    188 0.38
    210 0.47
    267 0.89
    327 1.50
    362 1.82
}{\growth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        width=\linewidth,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        xlabel=Zeit,
        ylabel=Optische Dichte,
        x unit=\si{\minute},
        y unit=,
        ymode=log,
%       xtick={0,100,150,200,300},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north west
        ]
        \addplot[
            thick,
            mark=*,
            mark options={fill=red},
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            every node near coord/.style={anchor=-40},
            color=blue,
            ] table [x=X,y=Y,col sep=tab,meta index=2] {\growth};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used thinks like

```
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
```

within the command for `every node near coord/.style`, but I can't achieve the right format for the decimal seperator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you've listed `point meta=explicit symbolic`, which means `pgfplots` treats the `point meta` like a string and doesn't use `\pgfmathprintnumber` for printing. You can instead use the option `point meta=explicit` (not `explicit symbolic`) with the `/pgf/number format/use comma` to get what you want. Note that you need to specify `explicit` because otherwise, the `nodes near coords` will print the log transformed value of the `y` coordinate.

Note that there were some errors with your MWE that I fixed. In particular, the SX site doesn't save tabs, so the specification of your table (`col sep=tab`) wasn't quite correct (and in any case, I believe that `pgfplots` treats any whitespace as a column separator, so the specification of `tab` is not necessary here where there are no spaces between data), and the `meta index` needed to be `1` not `2`.

I also changed your axis to a `semilogyaxis` instead of using `ymode=log` and got rid of the `/pgf/number format/.cd` in the first line of the options, in case it might cause a problem (although to be honest, I don't think it actually does anything there).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    %strict,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    exponent-product=\cdot,
    detect-all
}

\pgfplotstableread{
    X   Y
    0   0.03
    63  0.04
    118 0.09
    188 0.38
    210 0.47
    267 0.89
    327 1.50
    362 1.82
}{\growth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        /pgf/number format/use comma,
        width=\linewidth,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        xlabel=Zeit,
        ylabel=Optische Dichte,
        x unit=\si{\minute},
        y unit=,
%       xtick={0,100,150,200,300},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north west,
        ]
        \addplot[
            thick,
            mark=*,
            mark options={fill=red},
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=explicit,
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=-40, /pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, fixed, precision=2},
            color=blue,
            ] table [x=X,y=Y,col sep=tab,meta index=1] {\growth};
        \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TechPharmacist Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

With all that `siunitx` settings, you can use

```
nodes near coords={$\num{\pgfplotspointmeta}$},
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    %strict,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    exponent-product=\cdot,
    detect-all
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
    X   Y
    0   0.03
    63  0.04
    118 0.09
    188 0.38
    210 0.47
    267 0.89
    327 1.50
    362 1.82
}{\growth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        width=\linewidth,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        xlabel=Zeit,
        ylabel=Optische Dichte,
        x unit=\si{\minute},
        y unit=,
        ymode=log,
        xtick={0,100,150,200,300},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north west
        ]
        \addplot[
            thick,
            mark=*,
            mark options={fill=red},
            nodes near coords,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords={$\num{\pgfplotspointmeta}$},
            every node near coord/.style={anchor=-40},
            color=blue,
            ] table [x=X,y=Y,col sep=space,meta index=1] {\growth};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]